# An object or column name is missing or empty GEOMETRY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do a geometric union but it's not working

```
select b.[Region],geometry::UnionAggregate(geom.MakeValid()) into dbo.DRShape 
from [dbo].[departements2] a join [dbo].[BM_REGIONFR] b 
on a.[code_insee] = b.[dep_2] 
group by b.Region
```

> Msg 1038, Niveau 15, État 5, Ligne 1
>   An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.

Comment: Just add alias for all columns. The message is quite clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a table using `SELECT INTO`, the table needs a column name for each column. Your second column result is missing an alias (that will turn into a column name).

```
select 
    b.[Region],
    geometry::UnionAggregate(geom.MakeValid()) AS Geo -- Add Alias!!
into 
    dbo.DRShape 
from [dbo].[departements2] a join [dbo].[BM_REGIONFR] b 
on a.[code_insee] = b.[dep_2] 
group by b.Region
```

If you comment the `INTO dbo.DRShape` and you see that your query runs OK, means that the problem is the creation of your new table.

Comment: Thank you so much !